# Css border bug - oblique rendering

Tags: css, border

We have the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/Z92Qp/

As you can see the green line that appear on mouse hover is "oblique" on the right side.
[see the image](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/543/72358279.jpg)

Is that a bug of the browsers?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not a bug, [that's just how borders are drawn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-does-this-css-triangle-shape-work).

Comment: It's not a bug. Browsers render border this ways.

Comment: Think of it as a picture frame - easiest way to join the corners is at 45 degree angles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug its how the browsers choose to render the border.

See this example I mocked up.
http://jsfiddle.net/blowsie/Uss7X/

[image]

Answer (score 2):

No, borders are designed that way, to meet half way as seen [here](http://www.tizag.com/cssT/border.php)

Answer (score 1):

Hey now used to box shadow as like this

```
li:hover {
                box-shadow: 0 4px 0 0 #00FF00;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 0 0 #00FF00;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 0 0 #00FF00;

            }
```

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Z92Qp/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

CSS borders are drawn with diagonal corners.

Otherwise, if you had 2 different colours for bottom and right (blue & red for e.g), what would happen in the corner? Would it be all red, or all blue?

This is well known, and is even exploited to make [CSS Triangles](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/)